# Heard our Prayer Really?

Tags: beshalach, tefilla, selichot

Every morning we say

וְאֶת זַעֲקָתָם שָׁמַעְתָּ עַל יַם סוּף

That would seem to be wrong as we know Hashem told Moshe

וַיֹּאמֶר יְ־הֹוָ־ה אֶל מֹשֶׁה מַה תִּצְעַק אֵלָי דַּבֵּר אֶל בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְיִסָּעוּ:

The same applies in Aneinu by sleichos?

Comment: I don't understand. If he told us to stop yelling, doesn't that mean he heard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Onkelus says that Hashem told Moshe to tell the Jews to stop praying as he answered them already.